# powershell: Remove-DhcpServerv4Lease does not remove existing leases

Tags: powershell, dhcp

I want to delete all DHCP leases and reservation from server WSKELLER. From the documentation I seem to understand that this would be accomplished with:

```
Get-DhcpServerv4Scope -ComputerName WSKELLER | Remove-DhcpServerv4Lease -ComputerName WSKELLER
```

The cmdlet does find all the leases, yet it throws for each lease the following error:

```
Remove-DhcpServerv4Lease : Failed to delete lease 10.10.12.32 from scope 10.10.0.0 on DHCP server WSKELLER.
At C:\admin\removeDhcpDns.ps1:8 char:48
+ ... mputerName WSKELLER | Remove-DhcpServerv4Lease -ComputerName WSKELLER + 
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ResourceExists: (10.10.12.32:root/Microsoft/...cpServerv4Lease) [Remove-DhcpServerv4Lease], CimException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : DHCP 20019,Remove-DhcpServerv4Lease
```

Obviously I am doing some mistake. But which one?

Comment: Does the account you use have the required permissions to remove the leases?

Comment: I start the script from an administrative (elevated) powershell. Should I do more?

Comment: Possibly, if the user account you are launching the shell from does not have permissions to the write to the DHCP server you will not be able to remove the leases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your error: `+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : DHCP 20019,Remove-DhcpServerv4Lease`

From: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363378(v=vs.85).aspx

> ERROR_DHCP_RESERVED_CLIENT
>   20019
>   The specified DHCP client is a reserved client.

It looks like you're trying to delete a reservation. If that is intentional, then you will need to use the `Remove-DhcpServerv4Reservation` cmdlet instead.